# Grouping where column is different

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) which looks like:

```
df = {'quarter':['Q1','Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q3','Q4','Q4','Q4'],
         'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
         'score':['DD','DD','DD','D','DD','DD','D','D','D','D','D','D']

         }



   quarter  id   score
0       Q1   1      DD
1       Q1   2      DD
2       Q1   3      DD
3       Q2   1       D
4       Q2   2      DD
5       Q2   3      DD
6       Q3   1       D
7       Q3   2       D
8       Q3   3       D
9       Q4   1       D
10      Q4   2       D
11      Q4   3       D
```

I am trying to count by id for each quarter where the score is different between quarters.  For example an id would get counted in for Q2 if the score for that id in Q1 was DD and the score for that id in Q2 was D.  So in the end I have an output that looks like:

```
   count
Q1    
Q2    1
Q3    2
Q4    0
```

There is no count value for Q1 as there was no previous quarter to compare.

I have tried groupby but can't work in the previous quarters score for a specific id.

```
df.groupby(['quarter','id']).size().reset_index().groupby('Quarter').count()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First reshape by `pivot`, compare shifted values with `ne` for not equal and count `True`s values by `sum`, last set first value to `NaN`:

```
df1 = df.pivot('quarter','id','score')
s = df1.shift().ne(df1).sum(axis=1).astype(float)
s.iat[0] = np.nan
print (s)
Q1    NaN
Q2    1.0
Q3    2.0
Q4    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  When I implement your solution I get: Q1    NaN
Q2    3.0
Q3    3.0
Q4    3.0
dtype: float64 Can you think of a reason why this might be please?

Comment: @Stacey - With sample data? Values `score` are floats? Or strings?

Comment: Thanks, they are strings

Comment: Problem is with sample data?

Comment: Doh, My bad sorry, assigned an incorrect data-frame.  Thanks for your help!